# I want to boot ubuntu-12.04 with USB

Tags: boot, usb

I am using ubuntu-9.04.I want to install the new version of Ubuntu.

So I download the new version and insert it in the USB by using *startup disk creator* but when I go to boot it from usb it shows :

```
'SYSLINUX 3.63...........Unknown keyword in configuration file
boot:
_ '
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with the files in your usb, namely, the 'boot' file.
Reformatting your usb and creating it again should fix it.

If it doesn't, try using some other boot disk creator like Rufus or UNetbootin.

http://rufus.akeo.ie/

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/